# RxJS - zip multiple subscribes results in ts compiler error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

i have an angular service that returns a `filterObservable`.

I want to combine multiple calls via `Rx.Observable.zip()`.

It works just as expected, but my typescript compiler throws an error for my method:

`error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

could you give me a hint, what I am doing wrong and how to solve the error?

```
protected getCombinedResults(ids:number[]) {
    let observablesToGetZipped = ids.map(id => this.myService.loadResource(id));

    if (observablesToGetZipped.length > 1) {
      return Rx.Observable
        .zip(observablesToGetZipped)
        .take(1);
    }

    return observablesToGetZipped[0].take(1);
  }
```

i call the method like this:

```
this.getCombinedResults([1,2,3,4,5]).subscribe(result => { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone who is interested in the solution:**

this did the trick for me

```
return Rx.Observable
    .zip.apply(Rx.Observable, observablesToGetZipped)
```